# nvim-completion-manager: neovim shows a Python syntax error in cm.py when opening a new file, I despite no actual syntax error in file

Tags: python, vim, neovim, manjaro, i3

In `~/.config/nvim/plugged/nvim-completion-manager/pythonx/cm.py`, line 151 is

```
        self.nvim.call('cm#complete', name, ctx, startcol, matches, refresh, async=True)
```

I'm using Python 3.8 and copying the file into an online interpreter for Python does not result in any syntax errors, so it confuses me that neovim is interpreting it as such.
I get `Error detected while processing function <SNR>35_on_core_channel_error`
[image: Shows when nvim starts]

My `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` is

```
call plug#begin()
Plug 'roxma/nvim-completion-manager'
Plug 'SirVer/ultisnips'
Plug 'honza/vim-snippets'
call plug#end()
```

I tried replacing the leading spaces with tabs but I got the same output.

All of this is followed directly from https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/how-to-install-neovim-and-plugins-with-vim-plug/

File: https://onlinegdb.com/ByyfKgK6w (raises an error, but syntax is fine).

Comment: Answered at https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/28609/18609

Comment: Thank you. I posted it on here before discovering the vi/vim stack exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace

```
Plug 'roxma/nvim-completion-manager'
```

with

```
Plug 'ncm2/ncm2'
```

in `init.vim`